# python pygameを用いてマイコンボードからのデータをリアルタイム処理を行う

Tags: python, pygame

このサイトhttps://algorithm.joho.info/arduino/python-serial-temperature-graph/を用いてarduinoとの通信を行って、グラフをリアルタイム表示させたいです。
textの方は問題なく表示されているのですが、グラフの方が表示することができないです。
なにか問題点などあるのでしょうか？

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import serial
import sys

def main():
    ser = serial.Serial("COM6")  # COMポート(Arduino接続)
    temps = [0]*100              # 温度格納
    t = np.arange(0,100,1)
    plt.ion()
    pygame.init()                # Pygameを初期化
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))   # 画面作成(100×100)
    pygame.display.set_caption("voltage")         # タイトルバー
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)              # 文字の設定

    while True:
        screen.fill((0,0,0))            # 画面のクリア
        temp = ser.readline().rstrip()   # \nまで読み込む(\nは削除)
        temp = temp.decode()
        text = font.render(temp + "[V]", False, (255,255,255))    # 表示する文字の設定
        screen.blit(text, (10, 10))     # レンダ，表示位置
        pygame.display.flip()           # 画面を更新して、変更を反映
        # 温度データのリスト更新
        temps.pop(99)
        temps.insert(0,float(temp))
        # グラフ表示設定
        line, = plt.plot(t, temps, 'r-',label="Temperature[C]") # Y軸更新
        line.set_ydata(temps)
        plt.title("Real-time temperature")
        plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
        plt.ylabel("Temperature [Celsius]")
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid()
        plt.xlim([1,100])
        plt.ylim([0,5])
        plt.draw()
        plt.clf()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # 終了ボタンが押されたら終了処理
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                ser.close()
                plt.close()
                sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

[matplotlib.figure.canvas.flush_events](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.flush_events) を使う方法はどうでしょうか。これで一応はリアルタイムに表示される様になります。

※ legend の表示位置ですが `plt.legend(loc='upper right')` などとして表示位置を固定すると良いかと思います

```py
def main():
          :

    while True:
          :
        ## don't need to call plt.draw() if clearing the figure with plt.clf()
        #plt.draw()
        ## flush the GUI events for the figure
        plt.figure(1).canvas.flush_events()
        plt.clf()
          :
```

Answer (score 0):

直前の質問と同様の環境だと、Windowsでやっていると思われますが、その場合は以下の記事が当てはまるでしょう。
紹介記事では動作しない原因は`plt.show()`としていますが、`plt.draw()`も同様のようです。

なので、**`plt.draw()`を`plt.pause(interval)`に変える** ことが対策になるでしょう。

[matplotlibでリアルタイム描画](https://qiita.com/hausen6/items/b1b54f7325745ae43e47)

> 調べてみると`show()`ではなくて`draw()`を使おう!みたいな記事とか，..途中省略.. Windows環境だとグラフに一度でも触るとGUIが固まったりしてとてもじゃないけど使えなかったりした．
>
> 結論は`plt.show()`の代わりに`plt.pause(interval)`を使うということ．
>
> ```
> # 一番のポイント
> # - plt.show() ブロッキングされてリアルタイムに描写できない
> # - plt.ion() + plt.draw() グラフウインドウが固まってプログラムが止まるから使えない
> # ----> plt.pause(interval) これを使う!!! 引数はsleep時間
> plt.pause(.01)
> ```

関連：[How do I plot in real-time in a while loop using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11874767/9014308)

ただし、jupyter notebook だと何か別の影響があるかもしれないので、まずは **素のPython だけで試してみてください。**

Answer (score 0):

@kunifさんのご回答内容に加えて、`plt.ylim([0,5])`も問題です。
これでは0℃～5℃までしか表示されません。

ご質問のリンク先にあるソースでは`plt.xlim([0,100])`を`plt.xlim([0,20])`に変更し、目盛線の間隔も書き換えられているようです。
下記はセンサー無しで動くように10℃～20℃のランダムなダミーデータを入れるサンプルコードです。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import serial
import sys
import random
import time

def main():
    # ◆□ テストのため改修 □◆
    #ser = serial.Serial("COM6")  # COMポート(Arduino接続)
    temps = [0]*100              # 温度格納
    t = np.arange(0,100,1)
    plt.ion()
    pygame.init()                # Pygameを初期化
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))   # 画面作成(100×100)
    pygame.display.set_caption("voltage")         # タイトルバー
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)              # 文字の設定

    while True:
        screen.fill((0,0,0))            # 画面のクリア
        # ◆□ テストのため改修 □◆
        temp = str(random.randint(10, 20))
        #temp = ser.readline().rstrip()   # \nまで読み込む(\nは削除)
        #temp = temp.decode()
        text = font.render(temp + "[V]", False, (255,255,255))    # 表示する文字の設定
        screen.blit(text, (10, 10))     # レンダ，表示位置
        pygame.display.flip()           # 画面を更新して、変更を反映
        # 温度データのリスト更新
        temps.pop(99)
        temps.insert(0,float(temp))
        # グラフ表示設定
        line, = plt.plot(t, temps, 'r-',label="Temperature[C]") # Y軸更新
        line.set_ydata(temps)
        plt.title("Real-time temperature")
        plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
        plt.ylabel("Temperature [Celsius]")
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid()
        plt.xlim([1,100])
        # ◆□ TODO 書き換え □◆
        #plt.ylim([0,5])
        plt.ylim([0,40])
        plt.draw()
        # ◆□ TODO 追記 □◆
        #plt.pause(0.01)  # ほぼリアルタイム描画
        plt.pause(0.5)    # テストのため0.5秒待機
        plt.clf()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # 終了ボタンが押されたら終了処理
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                plt.close()
                sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```